# Infopath Form requires me to Submit twice due to Slow Validation

Tags: infopath, validation, submit

I have created an InfoPath form that is connected to a SharePoint list.
Apparently you can't use the Developer option in InfoPath if it's a List Form (Stupid, but hey).

Form Contents (in Order):

- 4 x Dropdowns
- 1 x Multiline
- 1 x Text
- 1 x Submit Btn

The Dropdowns and Multiline all require validation.

When I click on Submit it does nothing!

When I click on it again, it Submits.

Sometimes it throws out an error saying that the Comments Field (Multiline) does not have text/failed validation.

I've worked out that the validation only happens once you click outside of the Field.
So I'm assuming that when I click on Submit, it does not Validate in time and that the Submit Button runs it's processes before the Validation runs.

How can I rectify this?
(I do not have the Developer Option Available as it is a SP List Form.

Comment: Are you filling this out in the browser or the thick client filler?  If the former, are you submitting from the toolbar/ribbon or does your form have it's own submit button?

Comment: Hi,Thx for your response. It's filled out in the browser and has it'es own Submit Button.

Comment: Here is a Screenshot of the form (hosted on SharePoint Intranet) - https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=a5c6a82e68c643ad&page=self&resid=A5C6A82E68C643AD!150&parId=A5C6A82E68C643AD!105&authkey=!Ag8y7VY40A3u8mg&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share&type=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved...

All I did was set postback to "Never" in the Multi-line Text Box ("Comments") properties.
So now it does the validation locally instead of checking the server as there is nothing on the server to validate.

The validation is only used to confirm that there is text in the Text Field.
* Only do a postback if there is something to retrieve or populate!

Hope this helps others.

Regards,
RaveWolf

Comment: "Never" for "Postback Settings" is not being displayed/available in my case, as a potential option to choose from, at all. Hm, any other solution?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDZF0.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDZF0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

@RaveWold nailed it.. in case someone doesn't know how to do that :

1. Right-click on the rich text field and select Rich Text Box
   Properties.
2. In the "Browser forms" tab (last one), select "Never" for "Postback
   Settings".
3. Quick publish..good to go.